# How to draw Intersection of line and solid object in BricsCAD

Tags: macros, draw, intersect, cad

It is posible to set up BricsCAD in 3D to automatically create intersection points or intersection line during drawing line going through surface (in my case there are two points inner and outer surface or short line inside)? I would like to use this in the macro to draw a lot of lines going through.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I put the same question on AutCAD forum as well. And there is answer: The solution in is to not use lines, but solid objects. In my case the result is to create the cylinders and use the lines along the axes, because on the place of penetration (intersection) should be drilled holes. Than it is possible to use subtraction to subtract material on the place of intersection. The both objects should be 3D solid (ACIS) type of objects. The result is object with holes as needed.